# Symfony2/Doctrine: how to add more of the same entity in the same collection?

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm designing a Symfony2 application where a Computer entity is associated with several hardware components, i.e. Mainboard, CPU, Disk, MemoryModule and so on. They are all represented by entities in Doctrine.

What I need to do is associate more than one Disk with the same Computer, in case it has more than one identical Disks in its hardware configuration. I would like to avoid multiple fields like Disk1, Disk2, etc., so I set a ManyToMany relationship between the two entities:

Entity **Computer**:

```
//... 

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Components\Disk", inversedBy="computers")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="computers_disks")
 */
protected $disks;
```

Entity **Disk**:

```
//...
enter code here
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Computers\Computer", mappedBy="disks")
 */
protected $computers;
```

For example, I run this code in my Fixtures:

```
$testComputer = new Computer();
$cpu = $this->getReference('CPU-i3-1150');
$disk = $this->getReference('Disk-wd500blue');

//...

$testComputer->setCpu($cpu);        // OK
$testComputer->addDisk($disk);      // OK
$testComputer->addDisk($disk);      // ERROR
```

The error I get is, as expected, an Integrity constraint violation:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-14'
for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How do I overcome this? I think I should somehow add an index on the join table but I don't know if it's even possible.

**EDIT**: I also tried - just for the sake - with unidirectional relationship, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying to do with a standard `ManyToMany` Doctrine relationship because by definition these relationships are unique, i.e. they only hold unique combinations of both entities.

But you can do this using an "association" entity which acts as an in-between for both entities:

```
class Computer { 
    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ComputerDisk", mappedBy="computer") 
     **/ 
    protected $computerDisks; 
} 

class ComputerDisk { 
    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Computer", inversedBy="computerDisks") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="computer_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
     **/ 
    protected $computer; 

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Disk", inversedBy="computerDisks") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="disk_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
     **/ 
    protected $disk; 

} 

class Disk { 
    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ComputerDisk", mappedBy="disk") 
     **/ 
    protected $computerDisks; 
}
```

This will be similar to a many to many relationship, only that this middle entity will be used to hold the relationship and it does not have to be unique.

In your case probably the relationship between this entity and the disk can be unidirectional, as you probably do not need to know which computers hold each disk so the field in the Disk entity and the inversedby in the ComputerDisk association with this entity can be ommited

One advantage of this approach is that the relationship can hold extra fields, so you could do things like have a `$diskBay` field which held the location of the disk

Comment: Thank you very much Carlos, in fact I had heard of a "Joiner class" in another question. It's very helpful.

I also would like to manage it in a Sonata Admin form, i.e. to have a "Add Disk" button, but I guess it's not trivial. 

Maybe it's better if I open another question for that? Do you have any experience?

Comment: First try to implement it and if you don´t get it to work, open a different question